# Add/Remove favorites multiple products with local storage and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I want to integrate a system to bookmark products. everything is stored locally (Localstorage). A click on an icon allows to put it in favorites and another click to remove it. The heart icon is empty when the product is not in favorites and filled when it is in favorites)

It works very well with one product.(perfect if the visitor is directly on the product page)

=> https://jsfiddle.net/b5ukqmLx/5/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products_fav'));
 if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];

        var theIndex = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < existingEntries.length; i++) { // search if product ID already in localstorage
            if (existingEntries[i].id == '317') {
                theIndex = i;
         $(".add_favorite").addClass("active");
                break;
            }
     }


  $(".btn_toggle").click(function(){
     $(".add_favorite").toggleClass("active");
fav_local('products_fav','317','Apple iPhone 11 Pro (512 Go) - Gris Sidéral','apple-iphone-11-pro-gris-sideral-512-go-36156','https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/0190199391482_h_f_l_0','1559.00','11');
  });

});

function fav_local(name, new_search, title, slug, image, best_price, total_in_stock){

    if(window.localStorage!==undefined) {
        var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
        if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];


        var theIndex = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < existingEntries.length; i++) { // search if product ID already in localstraoge
            if (existingEntries[i].id == new_search) {
                theIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (theIndex == -1){ // not present => add
            var entryId = new_search;
            var entryTitle = title;
            var entrySlug = slug;
            var entryImage = image;
            var entryBest_price = best_price;
            var entryTotal_in_stock = total_in_stock;

            var date = new Date();
             date.setTime(date.getTime());
             var date_product = date.toGMTString();

            var entry = {
                "id": entryId,
                "title": entryTitle,
                "slug": entrySlug,
                "image": entryImage,
                "best_price": entryBest_price,
                "total_in_stock": entryTotal_in_stock,
                "date": date_product
            };
            // Save allEntries back to local storage
            existingEntries.push(entry);
            //sorted by date
            var sortedExistingEntries = existingEntries.sort(function compare(a, b) {
              var dateA = new Date(a.date);
              var dateB = new Date(b.date);
              return dateB - dateA;
            });
            // max 4 products
            if(Object.keys(sortedExistingEntries).length === 5) sortedExistingEntries.pop();
            //console.log(sortedExistingEntries);

            localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(sortedExistingEntries));

        } else {
      existingEntries.splice("+theIndex+",1);
      localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(existingEntries));

    }
    }
}
```

```css
i svg {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #f78554;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    cursor: pointer;
}
i.active svg {
    fill: #f78554;
}
```

```html
 <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <i class="add_favorite"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="50" height="50" style="">
        <path d="M21.317,3.761a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0L12,4.994l-1.177-1.23a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0,6.211,6.211,0,0,0,0,8.5L3.862,13.5v0L12,22h0l8.138-8.5v0l1.177-1.23A6.211,6.211,0,0,0,21.317,3.761Z" style="" class="btn_toggle" onclick=""></path>
    </svg></i>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to operate the system on a page where there are many products.

I do not know at all how to do it and I do not have a very high level in javascript.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

After a good night's sleep, I finally found the solution

=> https://jsfiddle.net/b5ukqmLx/14/

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<i class="add_favorite"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="50" height="50">
    <path d="M21.317,3.761a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0L12,4.994l-1.177-1.23a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0,6.211,6.211,0,0,0,0,8.5L3.862,13.5v0L12,22h0l8.138-8.5v0l1.177-1.23A6.211,6.211,0,0,0,21.317,3.761Z" class="btn_toggle" data-id="317"></path>
</svg></i>
<br>
<i class="add_favorite"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="50" height="50">
    <path d="M21.317,3.761a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0L12,4.994l-1.177-1.23a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0,6.211,6.211,0,0,0,0,8.5L3.862,13.5v0L12,22h0l8.138-8.5v0l1.177-1.23A6.211,6.211,0,0,0,21.317,3.761Z" class="btn_toggle" data-id="318"></path>
</svg></i>
<br>
<i class="add_favorite"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="50" height="50" >
    <path d="M21.317,3.761a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0L12,4.994l-1.177-1.23a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0,6.211,6.211,0,0,0,0,8.5L3.862,13.5v0L12,22h0l8.138-8.5v0l1.177-1.23A6.211,6.211,0,0,0,21.317,3.761Z" class="btn_toggle" data-id="319"></path>
</svg></i>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
i svg {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #f78554;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    cursor: pointer;
     transition: fill 1.5s,stroke 1s;
}
i.active svg {
    fill: #f6743c;
    transition: fill 1.5s,stroke 1s;
    stroke:#f6743c;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products_fav'));
  if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];

     $('[data-id]').each(function() {

       var dataId = $(this).data('id');
       var theIndex = -1;
        //var idProduct = $(this).attr("data-id");

       for (var i = 0; i < existingEntries.length; i++) { // search if product ID already in localstorage

        if (existingEntries[i].id == dataId) {
           theIndex = i;
           $(this).parents(".add_favorite").addClass("active");
           break;
         }
        }       


    })






  $(".btn_toggle").click(function(){
     $(this).parents(".add_favorite").toggleClass("active");

     var idProduct = $(this).attr("data-id");

     fav_local('products_fav',idProduct,'Apple iPhone 11 Pro (512 Go) - Gris Sidéral','apple-iphone-11-pro-gris-sideral-512-go-36156','https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/0190199391482_h_f_l_0','1559.00','11');

  });

});

function fav_local(name, new_search, title, slug, image, best_price, total_in_stock){

    if(window.localStorage!==undefined) {
        var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
        if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];


        var theIndex = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < existingEntries.length; i++) { // search if product ID already in localstraoge
            if (existingEntries[i].id == new_search) {
        var idToRemove= existingEntries[i].id;
        //console.log(idToRemove);
                theIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        //alert(theIndex);

        if (theIndex == -1){ // not present => add
            var entryId = new_search;
            var entryTitle = title;
            var entrySlug = slug;
            var entryImage = image;
            var entryBest_price = best_price;
            var entryTotal_in_stock = total_in_stock;

            var date = new Date();
             date.setTime(date.getTime());
             var date_product = date.toGMTString();

            var entry = {
                "id": entryId,
                "title": entryTitle,
                "slug": entrySlug,
                "image": entryImage,
                "best_price": entryBest_price,
                "total_in_stock": entryTotal_in_stock,
                "date": date_product
            };
            // Save allEntries back to local storage
            existingEntries.push(entry);
            //sorted by date
            var sortedExistingEntries = existingEntries.sort(function compare(a, b) {
              var dateA = new Date(a.date);
              var dateB = new Date(b.date);
              return dateB - dateA;
            });
            // max 12 products
            if(Object.keys(sortedExistingEntries).length === 13) sortedExistingEntries.pop();

            localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(sortedExistingEntries));

        } else {
            var removeIndex = existingEntries.map(function(item) { return item.id; }).indexOf(idToRemove);
      existingEntries.splice(removeIndex,1);
      localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(existingEntries));

    }
    }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products_fav'));
  if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];

     $('[data-id]').each(function() {

       var dataId = $(this).data('id');
       var theIndex = -1;
        //var idProduct = $(this).attr("data-id");

       for (var i = 0; i < existingEntries.length; i++) { // search if product ID already in localstorage

        if (existingEntries[i].id == dataId) {
           theIndex = i;
           $(this).parents(".add_favorite").addClass("active");
           break;
         }
        }       
       
       
 })






  $(".btn_toggle").click(function(){
     $(this).parents(".add_favorite").toggleClass("active");
     
     var idProduct = $(this).attr("data-id");
     
     fav_local('products_fav',idProduct,'Apple iPhone 11 Pro (512 Go) - Gris Sidéral','apple-iphone-11-pro-gris-sideral-512-go-36156','https://boulanger.scene7.com/is/image/Boulanger/0190199391482_h_f_l_0','1559.00','11');

  });

});

function fav_local(name, new_search, title, slug, image, best_price, total_in_stock){

 if(window.localStorage!==undefined) {
  var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
  if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];


  var theIndex = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < existingEntries.length; i++) { // search if product ID already in localstraoge
   if (existingEntries[i].id == new_search) {
        var idToRemove= existingEntries[i].id;
        //console.log(idToRemove);
    theIndex = i;
    break;
   }
  }
  //alert(theIndex);

  if (theIndex == -1){ // not present => add
   var entryId = new_search;
   var entryTitle = title;
   var entrySlug = slug;
   var entryImage = image;
   var entryBest_price = best_price;
   var entryTotal_in_stock = total_in_stock;

   var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime());
    var date_product = date.toGMTString();

   var entry = {
       "id": entryId,
       "title": entryTitle,
       "slug": entrySlug,
       "image": entryImage,
       "best_price": entryBest_price,
       "total_in_stock": entryTotal_in_stock,
       "date": date_product
   };
   // Save allEntries back to local storage
   existingEntries.push(entry);
   //sorted by date
   var sortedExistingEntries = existingEntries.sort(function compare(a, b) {
     var dateA = new Date(a.date);
     var dateB = new Date(b.date);
     return dateB - dateA;
   });
   // max 12 products
   if(Object.keys(sortedExistingEntries).length === 13) sortedExistingEntries.pop();

   localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(sortedExistingEntries));
       
  } else {
   var removeIndex = existingEntries.map(function(item) { return item.id; }).indexOf(idToRemove);
      existingEntries.splice(removeIndex,1);
      localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(existingEntries));

    }
 }
}
```

```css
i svg {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #f78554;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    cursor: pointer;
     transition: fill 1.5s,stroke 1s;
}
i.active svg {
    fill: #f6743c;
    transition: fill 1.5s,stroke 1s;
    stroke:#f6743c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<i class="add_favorite"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="50" height="50">
    <path d="M21.317,3.761a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0L12,4.994l-1.177-1.23a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0,6.211,6.211,0,0,0,0,8.5L3.862,13.5v0L12,22h0l8.138-8.5v0l1.177-1.23A6.211,6.211,0,0,0,21.317,3.761Z" class="btn_toggle" data-id="317"></path>
</svg></i>
<br>
<i class="add_favorite"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="50" height="50">
    <path d="M21.317,3.761a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0L12,4.994l-1.177-1.23a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0,6.211,6.211,0,0,0,0,8.5L3.862,13.5v0L12,22h0l8.138-8.5v0l1.177-1.23A6.211,6.211,0,0,0,21.317,3.761Z" class="btn_toggle" data-id="318"></path>
</svg></i>
<br>
<i class="add_favorite"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="50" height="50" >
    <path d="M21.317,3.761a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0L12,4.994l-1.177-1.23a5.581,5.581,0,0,0-8.14,0,6.211,6.211,0,0,0,0,8.5L3.862,13.5v0L12,22h0l8.138-8.5v0l1.177-1.23A6.211,6.211,0,0,0,21.317,3.761Z" class="btn_toggle" data-id="319"></path>
</svg></i>
</body>
</html>
```